# m2e and target folder in BusinessEvents Studio

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, businessevents

I'm having a project in BusinessEvents Studio (Eclipse) that I'm slowly turning into a Maven project. I've added m2e to BusinessEvents Studio and given the project a POM. Regardless of being in the "Studio Explorer" or the "Package Explorer" my `target` folder is shown in the tree (though being set to "Derived"). That in itself is fine by me, though it looks odd.

Now my BusinessEvents Studio has gotten in a loop where it seems to run Maven (m2e), which writes to the `target` folder, sees that something is written in the `target` folder and subsequently rerunning Maven (m2e). It even does so when checking "Build Automatically" to off.

Note that the reason for Mavenizing is an attempt to unit test things, so there is a purpose for having Maven run alongside BusinessEvents.

This loop is annoying, but also I want to have Maven do more incremental build tasks, effectively introducing a lot of idle waiting for me, the developer, being made worse by this loop.

Your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is caused to the following Eclipse issue:

["Windows 7 Libraries trigger rebuilds"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342931)

When I turned off "Refresh using native hooks or polling" (Preferences, General, Workspace) this behavior was over.

It is thus not a BusinessEvents Studio-specific issue. It is also not a m2e-related issue. Using any kind of non-trivial Maven POM makes is more visible, though.

(I think [Bug 342931](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342931) is definitely worth upvoting: in my personal opinion the auto-refresh is a very happy feature of Eclipse. I've had so many times Eclipse being out of sync with the file system after using tools like TortoiseSVN to mess with my work space outside of Eclipse.)